# How to use an Ion modal inside of a promise (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a dynamic modal that asks the user a question, and get the response as a True / False value.
I've created something similar before using an IonAlert.
Here is the code for the IonAlert inside of a promise.

```
// This is present at the top of the element
const [Alert] = useIonAlert();

// This is inside of a button click funtion
const start_anyway = await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    await Alert({
        header: "Are you sure you want to start?",
        subHeader: `These objects already exist on the item ${item}`,
        message: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(table),
        buttons: [
            {text: "Cancel", role: "Cancel", handler: () => {return resolve(false)}},
            {text: "Start", role: "Submit", handler: () => {return resolve(true)}}
        ],
    })
})

// I can get the result of the alert here.
console.log(start_anyway);
```

But I cannot seem to do the same with an IonModal.
It seems like an IonModal want the components inside of it to be present the moment the hook is created, but that is bad for me, because my element is dynamically generated.
Is there a way I could get an IonModal to behave the way this IonAlert is behaving?
Thanks in advance.